# How do I backup a g suite for business email account before deleting it?

Tags: g-suite

I have some accounts for ex employees that I don't need anymore... I would like to be able to reuse the license in g suite for business rather than just letting it sit.

From what i can tell with  G Suite for business, google vault is the backup method, but it looks like even there will cause it to be deleted from the vault if I delete the account. Do I have to just download it in outlook and then run a regular archive on it and stick it in google drive from there?

Thanks for looking and for any advice you can offer!

Answer (score 3):

Google lets you [download your data](https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/3024190) in a variety of formats.

Answer (score 3):

Using Google Vault will not help you since Vault removes data for users deleted from G Suite (part of their licensing policy). Let me summarize the options available for de-provisioning former employees' G Suite accounts:

1. You can use Google Takeout to export user's data offline (can be
   used once a month, you can access it at takeout.google.com)
2. Use Outlook or another email client to download the email messages and send them in PST or MBOX format
3. Use a 3rd party G Suite backup or archiving tool

I hope this helps you can see more details about the 3 options in [this](https://afi.ai/blog/g-suite-email-backup) blog post

Answer (score 1):

**Transfer or export files or important data**

You can transfer [ownership](https://support.google.com/a/answer/1247799) of files or [export the user's data](https://support.google.com/a/answer/100458). When you're deleting the user account, you can transfer Drive, Google+, and Google My Business data during the deletion process.

Source : https://support.google.com/a/answer/33314?hl=en

Answer (score 0):

You could also migrate a user's emails to another user, such as the administrator's account, so they will still be stored in the administrator's inbox. Then delete the user you don't need anymore.

Answer (score 0):

You can either transfer data of ex-employees to an active account, https://support.google.com/a/answer/1041297?hl=en

Or employ an on-premise backup tool, such as https://www.cubebackup.com

Comment: Hello and welcome to ServerFault! While providing links is useful, it would be _more_ helpful to the asker if you posted a summary of the steps involved on the link you posted as external links can go dead / be removed at any time. For more tips, see [answer].